# Karate - gatling - failed requested are not shown as KO

Tags: karate

I am using karate 0.9.6, maven gatling plugin - 3.1.0 (tried also with 3.0.2 - same result)

After simulation is finished I see following stats

```
> Global                                                   (OK=33     KO=0     )
> POST /token                                              (OK=10     KO=0     )
> POST /endpoint1                                          (OK=10     KO=0     )
> POST /endpoint2                                          (OK=8      KO=0     )
> POST /endpoint3                                          (OK=3      KO=0     )
> GET  /endpoint4                                          (OK=1      KO=0     )
> POST /endpoint5                                          (OK=1      KO=0     )
```

In this scenario, I should see 60 requests in global (OK + KO) cause that's the amount of requests that were executed but there's only 33 so it looks like failed tests are not considered by gatling. Looking into console I can see failed requests

My scenario looks like

```
Scenario: Perf test 

Given call read('classpath:some-reusable.feature') {args} #calling first 3 requests (token, endpoint1, endpoint2)
When call read('classpath:another-reusable.feature') {arg} #calling endpoint3 to endpoint5
Then match assertions
```

Scenario above works perfectly in normal situation.

Important here is that both reusable features call "generic" features where all possible API calls are defined, so the structure is

```
scr/java/test
|
|__api
|   |_generic1.feature (contains defined paths along with path to requests folder and HTTP methods)
|   |_...
|   |_genericN.feature
|
|__reusables
|   |_resubale1.feature (contains call read('classpath:api/genericN.feature@operation') and some 
|                        basic assertions like match responseStatus == correctStatus)
|
|__scenarios
    |_myTest.feature (contains call read('classpath:reusables/reusable1.feature') and other assertions that are required in test)
```

I created another scenario that contains all calls in it (so without reusing scenarios from other features)

```
Scenario: Perf test 

Given path '/somePath'
When method get
Then match assertions

Given path '/somePath1'
When method post
Then match assertions
```

and it started working as expected

So, the question is - is it possible to make it work with presented structure?  Or do I need change approach/create separate scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're actively working on the next release, so if you can try that, that would help: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

There's also a recent issue logged that may be related: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1382

So - if you see the same issue in the in-dev version, I request you to follow this process so that we get the simplest way to replicate: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - and we can take a look.

Of course if you can pitch in to investigate and contribute code, nothing like it !

Comment: I think the issue you linked is the same as mine, so once PR is merged I will try it out